# SvelteKit superforms in SSG mode gives typescript error for data.form. Where my `form`?

Tags: typescript, sveltekit, sveltekit-superforms

I got error for
**My application is working correctly.** My form adds *computers* correctly but typescript says:
`Property 'form' does not exist on type '{}'.`
Typescript talking about the form in `superForm(data.form,`  line

Please help! Typescript is driving me crazy.
I need form for first argument of superForm

### Where is `data.form` ?

`src\lib\db.ts` file content is :

```ts
import Dexie from 'dexie';

export interface Computer {
    id?: number;
    name: string | null;
}

export class DexieDatabase extends Dexie {
    computers!: Dexie.Table<Computer, number>;
    constructor() {
        super('DexieDatabase');
        this.version(1).stores({
            computers: '++id, name'
        });
        this.computers = this.table('computers');
    }
}

export const db = new DexieDatabase();
```

`src\routes\computers\add\+page.svelte` file content is :

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { db, type Computer } from '$lib/db';
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    import { superForm, setMessage } from 'sveltekit-superforms/client';
    import { z } from 'zod';
    const computerSchema = z.object({
        id: z.number().int().positive(),
        name: z.string().min(2)
    });
    export let data: PageData;
    const { form, errors, message, constraints, enhance } = superForm(data.form , {
        SPA: true,
        validators: computerSchema,
        onUpdate({ form }) {
            addComputer({ name: $form.name });
            setMessage(form, 'Valid data!');
        }
    });
    async function addComputer(comp: Computer): Promise<void> {
        await db.computers.add(comp);

    }
</script>

<h1>Add Computer</h1>

{#if $message}<h3>{$message}</h3>{/if}

<form method="POST" use:enhance>
    <label>
        computer Name<br />
        <input
            aria-invalid={$errors.name ? 'true' : undefined}
            bind:value={$form.name}
            {...$constraints.name}
        />
    </label>
    {#if $errors.name}<span class="invalid">{$errors.name}</span>{/if}

    <button>add</button>
</form>
```

Feel free to clone and Check out [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/kaanguru/mini-lock-it/blob/066b0b0317277d5bac682cef1a8365ba597ba034/src/routes/computers/add/%2Bpage.svelte#L12)

#### I am trying to get rid of typescipt error.

**NOTES**:
I do not have any more pages and I use "@sveltejs/adapter-static" , disabled SSR and enabled prerendering.